# How to set the width and height of a dcjs Heatmap based on the filtered group?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

In the sample of my code below, I want to set the width and height based on the number of values in the filtered group. Is there a best way to do this? Should I be tracking a count in the group add/remove functions?

```
    myHeatMap
        .width(45 * 20)
        .height(45 * 30)
        .dimension(heatDim)
        .group(heatGroup)
        .title(function (d) {
            return "Value: " + d.value;
        })
        .keyAccessor(function (d) { return d.key[0]; })
        .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.key[1]; })
        .colorAccessor(function (d) { return d.value; })
        .colors(["#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb", "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0", "#225ea8", "#253494", "#081d58"])
        .calculateColorDomain();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. In the general case, one would want the heatmap to change size when the number of rows or columns changes.

If you're not concerned with that, I think doing a count of of the elements is about the best you can do, with `d3.set` one easy way to get this:

```
var data = heatGroup.all();
var ncols = d3.set(data.map(function(x) { return x.key[0]; })).size();
var nrows = d3.set(data.map(function(x) { return x.key[1]; })).size();

myHeatMap.width(ncols*45).height(nrows*45)
```

Feel free to [file a feature request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new), or better yet, a PR, if you'd like to see the more general case. The heatmap is already doing something like this internally, although it doesn't have to compute the unique set since it relies on the ordinal scale for that.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I may look into submitting a PR if I get some time!

Comment: Gordon, I need heatmap to be resized when the underlying data changes (e.g. filters being applied). How do I do that?

Comment: Hi @GregaKešpret, please dig into [the code](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/heatmap.js) and find out! I don't have time to implement this feature right now, but I'll be glad to help out if you start on it. Just go ahead and fork the repo, and if you get stuck, file an issue with your work so far, and preferably with a working example.

Comment: I figured it out already, for posterity: just put the code from this answer into ```.on('preRedraw', function(chart) { ... }``` block.

Comment: Nice, that's a lot simpler than I was expecting. Thanks for sharing!